# Replace complete string if the first two characters match a pattern

Tags: r, regex, string

I am trying to replace the complete string if the two characters matches.Below is the code I am using in R

```
st <- "arzo"
ret <- gsub("^ar","honor8",st)
```

However it replacing only the portion where it find ar and giving the below output

```
honor8zo
```

Is there a way to replace complete string if two characters matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.*` to replace the whole string:

```
ret <- gsub("^ar.*","honor8",st)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl` to detect the presence of target strings, and then replace them. I added two more strings (`foo`, `bar`) to `st` to show that this approach will only replace the complete string if the condition (`^ar`) is met. `ret` is the result of replacement.

```
st <- c("arzo", "foo", "bar")

ret <- st
ret[grepl("^ar", ret)] <- "honor8" 
ret
[1] "honor8" "foo"    "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grep, in 1 line

```
st <- c("aaaa", "arzo", "bbb")
st[grep("^ar",st)] <- "honor8"
st
```